# How to write @html.actionlink in CSHTML after fetching from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am very new to Asp.net. Trying to create a Dynamic menu in Visual Studio 2015. In my Database, I have stored full actionlink like this  `@Html.ActionLink("Leave Status", "Leaves", "Office")` [Here Is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlgas.gif). but when I am fetching the action link I am not getting the desired result, provided images show what I need and what is output.

Could you please help me to solve the problem. I don't want to use another method like individually Controller and Page name. Is there any way to show Action link from the database directly. Here is the code

```
 @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dt in @ViewBag.DataPass2.Rows)
        {
           <li>
                @dt["mnud_page"]
           </li>
         }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

stored actionlink in database is very very wrong!

[read this tutorial](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/create-hyperlink-or-actionlink-html-actionlink-from-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-4-example)

you must create link dynamically

for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited my post. Is there any other way to show full Actionlink from detabase ?

Comment: for more details view this link:  https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/02/create-dynamic-menu-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Could you tell me how to put my Variable in @htmlactionLink that are coming form my database .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
List<string> actions = "Food, Work,Jump".Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

Then loop over the list.

Comment: Thank a lot but I stored the Action link in the database now to fetch it from database